# Nomenclature List shown, but not in text

Tags: nomenclature

I'm using package nomencl for my texnic project and it works fine so far. I use MikTex 2.9 and TeXnic 1.0.

Following code produces a list of my used nomenclatures at the beginning of the document, but unfortunately they are not shown in the text where I use them.

```
% Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\let\abk\nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}\makenomenclature
%%%----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
.....
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\include{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\printnomenclature
\abk{W3C}{World Wide Web Consortium} 
\end{document}
```

Neither abk nor nomenclature as command is working! W3C is only shown in the list!
Does anybody have an idea? Thanks in forward!

Comment: This is how `\nomenclature` is intended to work: it adds something to the nomenclature list, but doesn't do anything to the running text (`\index` works the same way).

Answer (score 3):

This is how `\nomenclature` is intended to work: it adds something to the nomenclature list, but doesn't do anything to the running text (`\index` works the same way).